# Laravel Eloquent one to many

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two Models, Company and Jobs. A Company can have many Jobs.

Job Model:

```
class Job extends \Eloquent {

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Company');
    }
}
```

Company Model:

```
class Company extends \Eloquent {

    public function jobs() {
        return $this->hasMany('Job');
    }
}
```

If I do the following, I want the `$job` object to have both the job & company objects in the same way I would if I did a SQL join such as:

```
SELECT * FROM  `jobs` JOIN company ON `company_id` = company.id WHERE jobs.`id` = 156;
```

Instead, if I do this

```
$job = Job::find($id);
var_dump($job);
exit;
```

`$job` has only the job.

If I do this:

```
$job = Job::find($id)->company;
var_dump($job);
exit;
```

I only get the company.

How do I get `$job` to be the equivalent of the SQL join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `->with()` function of Laravel to return the model `job` and it's associated model `company`:

```
$job = Job::with("company")->find($id);
```

You should then be able to access all fields in the `job` model like you normally would:

```
$job->field_1; 
$job->field_2; 
...
```

AND also the company model's fields:

```
$job->company->field_1;
$job->company->field_2;
...
```

I'm not 100% familiar with its usage in Laravel 5, but any further information can be found here:

[Laravel Documentation - Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: You're a star. Spent ages on this. Hadn't come across "With" before. Works just as I wanted now. Cheers.

Comment: Glad I could help! I did the same thing as you when I started with Laravel, this is much better though.